# How do i insert or update a record based on data whicha has a apostohphe in a dynamic sql?

Tags: sql-server

Here the  @Data has a value with apostophe(')s . how do i update or insert a data based on the data value which is having apostophe in a dynamic sql

suppose @data has one value abc and another value abc's it throwing error for the second one

`SET @SQL = ' Update '+ @ProcessCode + '_abc SET IS_IGNORING = 1 where Column_Name = '''+ @Column_Name +''' and [DATA] = ''' + @Data + ''' and Table_name = '''+ @Table_Name + ''''`

Generally what i found is a manual process of adding one more apostophe but i am not really sure how to use that in a dynamic sql where not all data in the table is same, few of the data records  has got this type of apostophe(')

Comment: use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and pass the value in as parameter

Comment: can you please give me a demo for better understanding @Squirrel

Answer (score 0):

Parameterized your query using sp_executesql

Example:

```
SET @SQL = 'Update ' + @ProcessCode + '_abc ' 
         + 'SET   IS_IGNORING = 1 ' 
         + 'where Column_Name = @Column_Name ' 
         + 'and   [DATA]      = @Data ' 
         + 'and   Table_name  = @Table_Name ' 

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, 
                   N'@Column_Name varchar(100), @Data varchar(100), @Table_Name varchar(100)',
                   @Column_Name, @Data, @Table_Name
```

Do read up more on dynamic query and SQL Injection

Comment: But i have already declared the variable before making the dynamic sql, Do i have to declare it again in this format and this statement is running inside a cursor?

Comment: You are NOT declaring it again in the above query. You are defining the data type for each of the parameter that you are passing in to `sp_executesql`. The definition is the second parameter of sp_executesql

Comment: if you can explain me how that will help me in dealing with apostophe(') with this ?

Comment: hi this is not working for the apostophe it says incorrect syntax near s

Answer (score 0):

You might find convenient to use parameterized queries, so you can replace static values with placeholders and then bind values to those placeholders before executing the query. It has certain advantages like better performance and helps to avoid SQL-injection attacks.

More info here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/ba-p/383483